# Proof of Borel-Wadge determinacy without using Borel determinacy?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, reverse-math

It's easy to prove Borel-Wadge determinacy from Borel determinacy.
But it's often said that Borel-Wadge determinacy is 'much weaker' than the latter. This is then argued by showing models in which the former is true but the latter false.

But is there also a proof of Borel-Wadge determinacy that doesn't use Borel determinacy, and in that way shows it's 'much weaker'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes (but I did not check the proof myself).  Unlike Borel determinacy, Borel Wadge determinacy is provable in second order arithmetic:
Louveau, A., and J. Saint Raymond. “Borel Classes and Closed Games: Wadge-Type and Hurewicz-Type Results.” Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, vol. 304, no. 2, 1987, pp. 431–467.

Comment: That paper can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1987-304-02/S0002-9947-1987-0911079-0/S0002-9947-1987-0911079-0.pdf). See also their later paper ["The strength of Borel Wadge determinacy"](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean.saint-raymond/preprints/wadge).